# Reference div id in my MVC model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a small hunk of code in my model that references a form.
Basically if the Name is null say "Name is required" I want to add, AND the div id == divid but I am new do MVC and I can't seem to figure out how to reference the DIV id in my code

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InsuredName))
        {
            retval.Add("Insured Name is required.");
        }
```

so after (InsuredName)) I want it to add && id == divid

Here is a snippet of my View

```
<div id="OSC" class="filter-div" style="display:none;">
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
            <div class="span4">
                <p class="text-info-left">Insured Name *</p>
                <p class="text-info-left">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InsuredName, new { id = "InsuredName", name = "InsuredName", tabindex = "1", type = "text", value = "" })</p>
            </div>
```

So while div id is equal to OSC AND the string is null or whitespace

Comment: How do you take the `InsuredName`? Is it comming from a form post or something like this? `div id` is a div in your view? Edit your question and explain more about it.

Comment: Edited for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can add Razor Validation

So the field that must be filled out will be required.

Have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites) for documentation.

Comment: I don't want to use razor. My if/else statements are in my View Model. I just want to add another condition to my if statement but am not sure how to call my DIV id from my cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read any value in the server side, you have to pass it from the client-side to server-side. To do this, you can use any input tag (textbox, checkbox, textarea, select, hidden, etc...).

In you case you could add a hidden value and pass the id of a div (or any other information you need) to this input hidden and read it on the server-side. For sample:

```
@Html.Hidden("DivId")
```

Then you can set the value in this hidden, for sample, using javascript (with jquery)

```
$("#DivId").val("OSC");
```

Then you can read the `DivId` property on the server-side.

```
if (InsuredName && DivId == "some value") 
{
    // code...
}
```